# How to make entire activity not respond to touches?

Tags: android

I have tried setFlags method but it did not work.

**Use case**:

To make entire activity not respond to user interaction (lets say, during an API call)

**Solution I found over the web:**

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);

getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

**Problem:**

If I execute the above code for an `activity B`, (My back stack is `A -> B`)

Touching the screen passes the events to `activity A` . Which is not a good behaviour.

Any Solution for this would be greatly helpful..
TIA.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

According to doc

```
     * @param ev The motion event being dispatched down the hierarchy.
     * @return Return true to steal motion events from the children and have
     * them dispatched to this ViewGroup through onTouchEvent().
     * The current target will receive an ACTION_CANCEL event, and no further
     * messages will be delivered here.
     */
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (ev.isFromSource(InputDevice.SOURCE_MOUSE)
                && ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                && ev.isButtonPressed(MotionEvent.BUTTON_PRIMARY)
                && isOnScrollbarThumb(ev.getX(), ev.getY())) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I edited the answer as

```
override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            return lock || return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)
        }
```

**Original Answer**

You can use a custom root layout, for example, if your activity level root layout is FrameLayout then you can use like this;

```
class LockLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : FrameLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    var lock = false

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        return lock || return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)
    }
}
```

When you set lock field as true, layout will not dispatch touch events to child views. Also if you want to disable back, then you should override activity onBackPressed as

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if(lock) return
    super.onBackPressed()
}
```

This is working very well with single activity approach but also you can adapt it for multiple activity.

Comment: Looks promising.. Will try. Thanks mate :)